# hide show fragment in android

Tags: android, android-fragments

i have a fragment and want hide and show with a button. I Use this code :

```
 public class Tablo extends FragmentActivity{
Fragment fg ;
Button click ;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tablo);
    fg = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.emojicons);
    click = (Button) findViewbyId(R.id.Button1);
    click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            fm.beginTransaction()
                    .setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out)
                    .show(fg)
                    .commit();
        }
    });
```

Log Error :

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to field 'int android.app.Fragment.mNextAnim' on a null object reference
        at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:809)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:452)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6145)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

Fragment in Xml :

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/emojicons"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="220dp"
    class="ir.m.sh.textsticker.PlusOneFragment"/>
```

My Fragment :

```
Android Studio PLusOneFragment
```

whats wrong ?

i want show and hide this fragment and tested all way but ...

Comment: Obviously `getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.emojicons);` didn't find a fragment for that *TAG* have you added the fragment somewhere?

Comment: Thats a layout you do not create an actual instance of the fragment and add it to the fragment manager. I think Florins answer fixes that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that your fragment object is null.
Try like this:

```
PLusOneFragment fg ;
Button click ;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_tablo);
if(savedInstanceState == null)
    fg = new PLusOneFragment();
else
    fg = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.emojicons);
click = (Button) findViewbyId(R.id.Button1);
click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        fm.beginTransaction()
                .setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out)
                .show(fg)
                .commit();
    }
});
```

Or if you want, instead of a PLusOneFragment object you can use a Fragment object and then when initialize it you can initialize it like that:
Fragment fg;
fg = new PLusOneFragment(); (where savedInstanceState is null);

Comment: I Use public class Tablo extends FragmentActivity   this is true ?

Comment: I edited my comment, I don't know exactly what do you mean.

Comment: PlusOneFragment is a fragment  in Tablo FragmentActivity .

Comment: Try to use import android.support.v4.app.Fragment instead of FragmentActivity.
And try to add your fragment in your activity xml file like that:
<fragment
            android:id="@+id/emojicons"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:layout="@layout/your_fragment_layout" />

Comment: Oh, now I see your edited post, if Tablo is your activity then Tablo should extend AppCompatActivity instead of FragmentActivity.

Comment: I Use AppCompatActivity But Error Log is this :(

Comment: Show the error from your Logcat (updated in a comment if it's not the same from your post)

Comment: please create a basic fargament and a activity show and hide your fragment and post all your code Please

Comment: You want to show your fragment whenever you press a button or you want to show it when your activity is created (I mean the fragment to be displayed when the activity is created and to remain there).

Comment: i use FrameLayout for Fragment in Layout.xml , and setVisibility(View.GONE);   . Work . Thank you